# Cocos 2D NullPointer Exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, 2d, cocos2d-android

I followed the guide in the following tutorial.
http://dan.clarke.name/2011/04/how-to-make-a-simple-android-game-with-cocos2d/

right on the first run i got the following error.

```
04-29 10:21:08.022: E/AndroidRuntime(12702): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 10
04-29 10:21:08.022: E/AndroidRuntime(12702): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-29 10:21:08.022: E/AndroidRuntime(12702):    at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCAtlasNode.updateBlendFunc(CCAtlasNode.java:168)
04-29 10:21:08.022: E/AndroidRuntime(12702):    at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCAtlasNode.<init>(CCAtlasNode.java:77)
04-29 10:21:08.022: E/AndroidRuntime(12702):    at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCLabelAtlas.<init>(CCLabelAtlas.java:40)
04-29 10:21:08.022: E/AndroidRuntime(12702):    at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCLabelAtlas.label(CCLabelAtlas.java:35)
04-29 10:21:08.022: E/AndroidRuntime(12702):    at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCDirector.setGLDefaultValues(CCDirector.java:593)
04-29 10:21:08.022: E/AndroidRuntime(12702):    at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCDirector.onSurfaceCreated(CCDirector.java:636)
04-29 10:21:08.022: E/AndroidRuntime(12702):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1349)
04-29 10:21:08.022: E/AndroidRuntime(12702):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1119)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That library is no longer updated. It will be better to start using: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/. It uses C++, to work on android, use JNI (Native code). Code can be ported to any other platforms, like IOS.

Hope it will help!

Comment: in fact, i dunno how to :D new here :P